# Nginx+puma deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

Good morning!

I'm trying to deploy a Puma server with Nginx. I've managed, till now, to create the Puma server, as my process table indicates: `ps aux | grep puma`:

```
superad+  5005  0.0  0.4  73076 17244 ?        Sl   May27   0:02 puma 3.11.4 (unix:///var/www/womaclub.com/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock)
superad+  5020  0.0  1.8 591892 71980 ?        Sl   May27   0:06 puma: cluster worker 0: 5005
superad+  5023  0.0  1.8 591816 71656 ?        Sl   May27   0:05 puma: cluster worker 1: 5005
```

However, I can't get Nginx to redirect and serve my application. Here's my nginx conf:

```
upstream puma {
server unix:///var/www/womaclub.com/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name womaclub.com www.womaclub.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/womaclub.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/womaclub.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/womaclub.com/current/public;
    access_log /var/www/womaclub.com/shared/log/puma_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/womaclub.com/shared/log/puma_error.log info;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
    location @puma {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass https://puma;

    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot
}
```

I've tried multiple configurations but until now I have not been able to work this out. Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Actually I don't get an error, the request is processed by Nginx but it doesn't serve the Rails application. It sends the request to the 500 error page of another application (there are multiple applications with different domains in a single VPS).

Comment: It sounds strange "Here's my nginx conf". If you have multiple domains, you should have something like /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf